# Estimating parameter of random sample

Tags: statistics

5 random numbers were recorded: 100,32,76,52,17. If we know that these are elements of random sample took from set {1,2, ..., N}, how do we estimate the parameter N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia article on the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) gives a formula in both the frequentist and the Bayesian framework.